# what number of threads to be created in thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading

Currently i am in a process of developing a application which can work in a multi threaded mode. As part of testing on my local machine (Intel Core I5) i tested with 4 threads. But now want to release the code for intense(regression) testing, so there any hard rule by which we can decide the number of threads to be created for processing.

I am not using any web or App server, instead i have written my logic to receive the request and then process it. Now During the processing, i receive the request on main Thread, and then i submit the call to `ExecuterService` where i need to decide the number of threads, then i process the request and each thread is again capable of returning the response.

I need to configure an optimum number of thread. I am trying to deploy my application on 16-Core, with 40GB Memory linux machine.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many threads should I use in my Java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130506/how-many-threads-should-i-use-in-my-java-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the optimal number of threads is equal to the number of cores in your machine. 
In practice, many operations are waiting for memory, IO, network or disk.

Try to execute only a single thread. If the CPU core load is 25% - you can try to create (4 x the number of cores in your machine) threads.

Note that increasing the number of threads will effect the time each thread will wait for network/disk/memory/IO, so it is somewhat more complex.

The best thing you can do is benchmark: Measure how much time it would take to complete 1,000,000 simulated requests - given different number of threads.

Comment: I would say your opening sentence is wrong, but the rest is pretty good advice.

Comment: For cpu intensive tasks it is actually `number of CPUs+1`

Comment: This calculation is ok for threads that are busy all the time. But if you have e.g. an application communicating over the internet, that often waits for a response you can use more threads.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum number of threads for an application can not be extracted via some well defined formula but it depends on the nature of your various tasks and your target environment.

- If your tasks are CPU intensive then, if you spawn too many threads the performance will degenerate as most of the time will be spend in context switching.
  For compute intensive tasks a general formula is `Ncpus+1`. You can determine the number of CPUs using `Runtime.availableProcessors`
- If your tasks are I/O intensive then most of the time you can use a much larger number of threads since, due to the fact that the threads are spending so much time in blocking tasks, all of the threads will be schedulable.

So taking these 2 into account you should estimate the `compute-time vs waiting-time` via a profiler or other similar tool.

You can try your benchmarks with various sizes until your estimate the optimal for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how cpu intensive your tasks are. But still you can assign one task to one core. So at the least you can go about creating as many threads as number of cores. That said, things may slow down depending on

- Your code doing lots of I/O.
- Lots of network I/O
- other CPU intensive tasks

If you create too many threads, there will be lots of time wasted in context switching. Unless you can come to a benchmark based on your own tests, go with threads=number of cores.